# How do I change the used PHP version?

Tags: drush

I am using Drush to update modules.
When I run the command php -v it correctly shows I am running version 5.5

I then use the command drush rf followed by drush up to perform any updates.

I am using the Schema.org Metatag module which requires php version 5.
The website is running php version 5.5.37

The default CLI version on Hostgator shared server is 5.4.45.
That is what I was originally using for drush. When I received the message below I found the path to use php 5.5 but I am still getting the same message.
So I can't figure out how it still sees php ver 5.4.45 and how to resolve this so it doesn't keep disabling that module.

When Drush runs an update I get the following message:
*Schema.org Metatag requires at least PHP 5.5. (Currently using PHP   [warning]
5.4.45)*

And then it disables the Schema Metatag module.

NOTE:
When I run command drush status:
PHP configuration: opt/php55/lib/php.ini
Drush version is 8.1.11

Thanks

### Extra information

.bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin 
export PATH 
alias composer="/opt/php55/bin/php ~/bin/composer.phar" 
alias drush="/opt/php55/bin/php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush.php"
```

.bashrc

```
 alias php='/opt/php55/bin/php' 
 alias composer='/opt/php55/bin/php ~/bin/composer'
 export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php55/bin/php'
```

- `php -v` returns PHP 5.5.37
- `which php` doesn't return anything
- `drush status` returns PHP configuration /opt/php55/lib/php.ini

But, when I use Drush to update a module I still get: `Schema.org Metatag requires at least PHP 5.5. (Currently using PHP [warning] 5.4.45)`

Answer (score 2):

- Find the path to php 5.5’s binary.
- Find the path to drush.

Execute

```
/path/to/php_55/bin/php /path/to/drush status
```

Comment: My .bash_profile
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
alias composer="/opt/php55/bin/php ~/bin/composer.phar"
alias drush="/opt/php55/bin/php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush.php"

My .bashrc
alias php='/opt/php55/bin/php'
alias composer='/opt/php55/bin/php ~/bin/composer'
export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php55/bin/php'

When I run following commands
php -v
PHP 5.5.37
which php
doesn't return anything
drush status
PHP configuration
/opt/php55/lib/php.ini

But, when I use Drush to update a module I still get: Schema.org Metatag requires at least PHP 5.5. (Currently using PHP [warning] 5.4.45)

Comment: @Jimmyk if you go to the status page, what php version does Drupal say it’s using?

Comment: @Jimmy Drush doesn’t source .bash_profile or any other/equivalent when it executes. Anything you have in there is pretty much irrelevant to Drush.

Comment: When you say status page you mean the command drush status? For PHP configuration: /opt/php55/lib/php.ini so that must mean PHP 5.5 But the version of Drush I am using is 8.1.11 Is that only 5.4? Does that mean I need to update Drush version?

Comment: Status page in your site. Log in then go to Reports > Status Page. Drush should be using 5.5 per your comment and the `DRUSH_PHP` var. I can only think that Drupal may be using a different one, 5.4.45. The drush and Drupal versions can be different.